# Loops in arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

Hi， I has a question in `Graph::Directed` using perl. I want to change the array name according to different index. How can I done this by only one loop to change the array name with the change of index. Below is the example that I want to show.

```
@v  = $g-> strongly_connected_component_by_index(0);
@v1 = $g-> strongly_connected_component_by_index(1);
@v2 = $g-> strongly_connected_component_by_index(2);
```

Your respond are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `my @AoA = map [$g->strongly_connected_component_by_index($_)], 0..2;` http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Declaration-of-an-ARRAY-OF-ARRAYS

Comment: You don't want dynamic variable names, that is a bad idea. It does not work with `use strict`, for one thing, and that is really bad. When you want dynamic names, you most often want a hash: `$hash{'name'} = 'Fred'`. But in your case, an array of arrays would be simpler. `$AoA[$index] = [ $g-> .... ($index) ]`.

Comment: I'm with @TLP, and here's an excellent 3-part story as to why you want to use a hash instead: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 1):

For the love of all things good, use a hash instead. In this case, you'd build an array-of-arrays:

```
my @components_by_index;
for (0..2) {
    $components_by_index[$_] = [ $g->strongly_connected_component_by_index($_) ];
}

print "$components_by_index[0][0]\n";
```

Mark Jason Dominus wrote a fabulous three-part story on not using variable values as variable names: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html